# ID3D10Blob return NULL

Tags: c++, directx-11

I have this weird error and can't find how to fix it.
I'm trying to make a vertex and pixel shader but when I'm calling them with CreateVertexShader and CreatePixelShader it return NULL. I have set my shader type to fx and and my shader model to 5_0.
I'm using Visual Studio 2015 on windows 10

When it gets created:

```
ID3D11Buffer* TriangleVertBuffer;
ID3D11VertexShader* VS;
ID3D11PixelShader* PS;
ID3D10Blob *VS_Buffer;
ID3D10Blob *PS_Buffer;
ID3D11InputLayout* VertLayout;
```

When I'm calling them:

```
//Compile Shaders from shader file
hr = D3DCompileFromFile(L"Effects.fx", 0, 0, "VS", "Vs_5_0", 0, 0, &VS_Buffer, 0);
hr = D3DCompileFromFile(L"Effects.fx", 0, 0, "PS", "Ps_5_0", 0, 0, &PS_Buffer, 0);

//Create shader objects
hr = D3d11Device->CreateVertexShader(VS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(), VS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &VS);
hr = D3d11Device->CreatePixelShader(PS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(), PS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &PS);
```

My Effects.fx class

```
float4 VS(float4 inPos : POSITION) : SV_POSITION
{
    return inPos;
}

float4 PS() : SV_TARGET
{
    return float4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

When I'm running it, it doesn't give an error but just a break point

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF71F191AC4 in AzuraEngine.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

and the debug says:

> - VS_Buffer   0x0000000000000000    ID3D10Blob *
> - &PS_Buffer  0x00007ff71f19f1f0 {AzuraEngine.exe!ID3D10Blob  *PS_Buffer} 
>     {0x0000000000000000 }   ID3D10Blob * *
> - &VS 0x00007ff71f19f1d8 {AzuraEngine.exe!ID3D11VertexShader  *VS} {0x0000000000000000 }    ID3D11VertexShader * *
>       D3DCompileFromFile  0x00007ff71f192950
>     {AzuraEngine.exe!D3DCompileFromFile}  void *
> - D3d11Device 0x000000c9ab0c78c0  ID3D11Device *
>       hr  0x8876086c  HRESULT

source script:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d10.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "D3DCompiler.lib")

#include <Windows.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3d10.h>
#include <DirectXMath.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>

using namespace DirectX;

bool InitScene();

HRESULT hr;
ID3D11Device* D3d11Device;

//Creating all variables to the shader
ID3D11Buffer* TriangleVertBuffer;
ID3D11VertexShader* VS;
ID3D11PixelShader* PS;
ID3D10Blob *VS_Buffer;
ID3D10Blob *PS_Buffer;
ID3D11InputLayout* VertLayout;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    if (!InitScene())
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}

bool InitScene()
{
    //Compile shader from file
    hr = D3DCompileFromFile(L"Effects.fx", 0, 0, "VS", "Vs_5_0", 0, 0, &VS_Buffer, 0);
    hr = D3DCompileFromFile(L"Effects.fx", 0, 0, "PS", "Ps_5_0", 0, 0, &PS_Buffer, 0);

    //Creating Verex and Pixel shader
    hr = D3d11Device->CreateVertexShader(VS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(), VS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &VS);
    hr = D3d11Device->CreatePixelShader(PS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(), PS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &PS);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: An access violation is definitely an error. This is _far_ too much code. You must have created a [minimal testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because you have been trying to debug this problem on your own for the last few days. Show it please.

Comment: Ok, heres a minimal testcase for it, it's gets the same error (The minimal test case is replaced with the full source code)

Comment: Out of curiosity Nicky, why don't you just use VS compiler instead of this deprecated function? This will make much more sense and will also make things easier on you since you will only have to read the object code and not compile it during run time(which is actually not accepted for the Windows Store).